# Strange behavior of QGraphicsItem::HOVER

Tags: qt, qgraphicsitem

I have this little problem. I have my `QGraphicsItem` with `setAcceptHoverEvents(true)` in constructor.

And here is strange thing - `hoverMoveEvent` works, but `hoverEnterEvent` or `hoverLeaveEvent` **not**.

I dont understand this. If you have met with this problem before, please help.